# List of Financial Index in Mathematica

Tags: curated-data, finance

I have to work with different Financial Futures Index in Mathematica using the function "InteractiveTradingChart". But, I can't able to find a complete list of all the available Financial Futures Index in Mathematica. Moreover, is not so clear the abbreviate nomenclature used by Mathematica to refer each financial futures Index (and also if Mathematica do the difference between financial index and financial futures index).

For example, if I would to work with data of interactive trading chart of DowJones Industrial Index, I could easily digit:

```
InteractiveTradingChart["DJ"]
```

but if I do the same command for other index for example "NSDQ" (Nasdaq), or german index "DAX", or italian index "FTSEMIB", it gives me no result, or other completely different financial assets.

So, there is a way to find the complete list of financial futures index available in mathematica database, so I can know the "exact" nomenclature requested in the function "InteractiveTradingChart"?

Comment: Does `FinancialData["Exchanges"]` help?